# hide/unhide rows - procedure too long

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA and trying to create a code to hide/unhide rows on a sheet 2 (named Charge Codes) based on a value of a cell in sheet 1 (F4) (Values 0-10). I'm currently using the code below and it works through cell F23, but then the procedure is too long. I need to replicate this for cells F4:F53, with each of those F cells having a different corresponding set of 10 rows to hide/unhide on sheet 2. Can anyone help me compile this? This is the example I'm using for F4:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "0" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "1" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("4:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "2" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("5:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "3" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("6:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "4" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:6").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("7:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "5" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:7").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("8:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "6" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("9:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "7" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("10:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "8" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("11:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "9" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False: Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("12:12").Hidden = True

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") And Target.Value = "10" Then Sheets(“Charge Codes”).Rows("3:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this on the Worksheets("Charge Codes") code sheet? i.e. Is **Target** on Worksheets("Charge Codes")?

Answer (score 1):

If I got my basic maths correct this should take care of your groups of hidden rows.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$F$4" Then
        Worksheets("Charge Codes").Cells(3, 1).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case 0, 10
                Worksheets("Charge Codes").Cells(3, 1).Resize(10, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
                Worksheets("Charge Codes").Cells(3, 1).Resize(Target.Value, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses nested Ifs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = ("$F$4") Then

    If Target.Value <> 0 Then
        Sheets("Charge Codes").Rows("3:12").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 10 Then
        Sheets("Charge Codes").Rows("3:12").Hidden = False
    Else
        Sheets("Charge Codes").Rows(3 + Target.Value & ":12").Hidden = True
        Sheets("Charge Codes").Rows("3:" & 2 + Target.Value).Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a logic to find the row numbers to hide

```
If Target.Address = ("$F$4") Then
Sheets("Charge Codes").Rows(3 & ":" & CDbl(Target.Value) + (CDbl(Target.Value) - 3)).EntireRow.Hidden = False: _
Sheets("Charge Codes").Rows(12 - CDbl(Target.Value) & ":" & 12).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: It will error when target value is anything less than 2, as it will return an negative row.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is just a sample and row numbers have to be modified according to logic that has to be applied, like the number of starting rows and number of rows that is required to be chosen.